# Proof of uniqueness for the Division algorithm of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I'm studying a proof of the Division algorithm of polynomials stated like this:

**Division algorithm of polynomials:** *Let $R$ be a unitary ring and $f, g \in R[x]$ with $f,g \neq 0$. Suppose that the leading coefficient of $g$ is unit of $R$. Then, there exist unique $q, r \in R[x]$ such that
$$f = qg + r,\quad \text{with}\; r = 0\;\text{or}\; \delta r < \delta g,$$
where $\delta p$ denotes the degree of any polynomial $p \in R[x]$.*

I have no problem with the proof of existence. However, in my algebra class we were given the following proof of uniqueness:

*Proof:* Let $q_1, q_2, r_1, r_2 \in R[x]$ be polynomials such that
$$f = q_1g + r_1 = q_2g + r_2,$$
with $r_i = 0$ or $\delta r_i < g$ for all $i \in \{1, 2\}$. We have that
$$(q_1 - q_2)g = r_2 - r_1,$$
so taking degrees, it follows that
$$\delta (q_1 - q_2)g = \delta (r_1 + r_2) \le \max \{\delta r_1, \delta r_2\} < \delta g.$$
If we suppose that $q_1 \neq q_2$, then $q_1 - q_2 \neq 0$ and, therefore,
$$\delta (q_1 - q_2)g = \delta (q_1 - q_2) + \delta g \ge \delta g,$$
a contradiction. So, we have that $q_1 = q_2$ and, therefore, that $r_1 = r_2$. Q.E.D.

I think that the inequality $\max \{\delta r_1, \delta r_2 \} < \delta g$ is false because $\delta g$ could be $0$ and, in that case, the inequality is not strict and, hence, we do not have a contradiction.

If we split into cases, we can do the same proof when $\delta g > 0$. However, I'm stuck when $\delta g = 0$. What I've tried is:
*Since we have that $\delta g = 0$, then $r_1 = r_2 = 0$ and, therefore,
$$(q_1 - q_2)g = 0.$$*

One would be tempted to say that since $g \neq 0$, then $q_1 - q_2$ must be equal to $0$ and we can conclude $q_1 = q_2$. However, since $R$ is not a field, we can't afirm that $R[x]$ is a domain and $q_1 - q_2$ could be something different to $0$.

Am I wrong on something? Any idea on how to correct the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a hypothesis that the leading coefficient of $g$ is a unit. If $g$ has degree zero then $g$ must be equal to a unit, $r$ must be zero, and $q$ is uniquely $f/g$